# Get Instance Name from Analysis Services like @@ServerName

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, dmv

Is there any way to get the current servername from an Analysis Services instance? Basically the same as `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` but for SSAS.

I have looked into    `SELECT * FROM $system.DISCOVER_INSTANCES`     but that returns an error:

*The 'INSTANCE_NAME' restriction is required but is missing from the request.  Consider using SYSTEMRESTRICTSCHEMA to provide restrictions.*

When attempting to use the `SYSTEMRESTRICTSCHEMA` I get the same error. When attempting to use `INSTANCE_NAME` I get the same error. When attempting to use the `SYSTEMRESTRICTSCHEMA` and specifying `INSTANCE_NAME` I get the same error.

Any help or insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you Server Name:

```
select [Value] as ServerName from $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_PROPERTIES where [PropertyName] = 'ServerName';
```

You don't need $system.DISCOVER_INSTANCES, but the syntax for that is:

```
select * from SYSTEMRESTRICTSCHEMA($SYSTEM.DISCOVER_INSTANCES, INSTANCE_NAME='MSSQLSERVER');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the error because the necessary parameters are not supplied to the functions. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126228(v=sql.110).aspx) and [here](http://www.ssas-info.com/VidasMatelisBlog/67_ssas-2008-rc0-new-function-systemrestrictschema-for-restricted-schema-rowsets-dmvs) to understand how to pass parameters to these functions.